# Extract value without quotation mark from MySQL JSON data type

Tags: mysql, json

I have started using the JSON data type in mysql 5.7. Is there a way to extract a value without the quotation marks? For instance when setting up a virtual index.

Example:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('{"type": "user" , 
"content" : { "username": "jdoe", "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe" } }');

mysql> SELECT json_extract(data,'$.type') FROM test;
+-----------------------------+
| json_extract(data,'$.type') |
+-----------------------------+
| "user"                      |
+-----------------------------+
```

How to get

```
+-----------------------------+
| json_extract(data,'$.type') |
+-----------------------------+
| user                        |
+-----------------------------+
```

?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use `->>` operator to extract unquoted data, simply!

```
SELECT JSONCOL->>'$.PATH' FROM tableName
```

Two other ways:

- `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(column, path))`
- `JSON_UNQUOTE(column->path)`

Note: Three different ways yield to the same command, as `EXPLAIN` explains:

> As with ->, the ->> operator is always expanded in the output of EXPLAIN, as the following example demonstrates:
>
> ```
> EXPLAIN SELECT c->>'$.name' AS name FROM jemp WHERE g > 2 ;
> SHOW WARNINGS ;
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
> Level: Note
> Code: 1003
> Message: /* select#1 */ select
> json_unquote(json_extract(`jtest`.`jemp`.`c`,'$.name')) AS `name` from
> `jtest`.`jemp` where (`jtest`.`jemp`.`g` > 2)
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

read more on MySQL Reference Manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path

Note: The `->>` operator was added in MySQL **5.7.13**

Comment: ->> is the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 72):

You can use JSON_UNQUOTE() method:

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(data,'$.type')) FROM test;
```

This method will deal with internal quotes,  for instance:

```
SET @t1 := '{"a": "Hello \\\"Name\\\""}';
SET @j := CAST(@t1 AS JSON);
SET @tOut := JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.a');
SELECT @t1, @j, @tOut, JSON_UNQUOTE(@tOut), TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM @tOut);
```

will give:

```
@t1     : {"a": "Hello \"Name\""}
@j      : {"a": "Hello \"Name\""}
@tOut   : "Hello \"Name\""
unquote : Hello "Name"
trim    : Hello \"Name\
```

I believe that the unquote is better in almost all circumstances.

Comment: This answer is best in my opinion because it will deal with internal quotations such as "Hello \"Name\"".

Comment: (added an example)

Answer (score 11):

A different method is;

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.type')) FROM test
```

Answer (score 10):

MySQL 8.0.21 supports [`JSON_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) function

> Extracts a value from a JSON document at the path given in the specified document, and returns the extracted value, optionally converting it to a desired type. The complete syntax is shown here:
>
> ```
> JSON_VALUE(json_doc, path [RETURNING type] [on_empty] [on_error])
> on_empty:
>        {NULL | ERROR | DEFAULT value} ON EMPTY
> on_error:
>        {NULL | ERROR | DEFAULT value} ON ERROR
> ```
>
> If not specified by a RETURNING clause, the JSON_VALUE() function's return type is VARCHAR(512)

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3821c86a23bd699b82a07c7b3622cae)**

```
SELECT json_value(data,'$.type')
FROM test;
-- user
```

Comment: That's a nice shortcut over the old style!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [CAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-converting-between-types) function to convert from json object to varchar

```
SELECT CAST(json_extract(data,'$.type') AS VARCHAR) FROM test;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried but this doesn't seem to work, although it looks like a clean solution. If I cast like VARCHAR it gives me ERROR 1064 (42000). I can cast it like CHAR, but then it keeps the quotation marks in place... It says here that VARCHAR is excluded from the allowed types http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: this does not work. it will cast it as a VARCHAR _with_ quotes

Comment: Use JSON_UNQUOTE(  instead of CAST(

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this when I had a string stored in the database that was a json object - this is how you can extract the whole raw object into another object:

```
set @json = '{"a":1}';
select json_object('object', json_extract(@json, '$'));
```

This returns

```
{"object": {"a": 1}}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also modify the column itself so that the quotes are not in the generated column

```
alter table your_table add your_field varchar(25) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM json_extract(json_field,'$.your_field')))
```

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT left(right(json_extract(data,'$.type'),5),4) FROM test;
```

Comment: This works! The only thing I like less about it is that it assumes the size of what to extract...

Answer (score -6):

I have found a solution that is most clean. CAST function didn't work, and @Pryanshu's answer can be made independent from the value length by using

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM json_extract(data,'$.type')) FROM test;
```

Comment: It's not safe command: `SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM '"\\"A\\""')` result is '\"A\'.

Comment: trimming won't correct things like (\"), it needs unquoting :)

Comment: This will mess up possible html inside the json